# How to navigate form one component to another component

Tags: angular2-routing

Here i'm using angular2 Here i Register `EditEmployeeByIdComponent`  in `EmployeeModule`  when user Click on that URL its shoud Redirect me to that Componet

**EditEmployeeByIdComponent**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core"
@Component({
    templateUrl:'../../ui/employee/EditEmployee.html'
})
export class EditEmployeeByIdComponent {
}
```

I Registerd EditEmployeeByIdComponent in EmployeeModule

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(EmployeeRoute), FormsModule, CommonModule, HttpModule],
    declarations: [EmployeeComponent, EditEmployeeByIdComponent],
    bootstrap: [EmployeeComponent],
    providers: [EmployeeService]
})

export class EmployeeModule {
}
```

From this Im calling

```
<tr *ngFor="let emp of employee">
    <a (click)="GetById(emp.Emp_Id)"> {{emp.EmpName}} </a>
</tr>


 GetById(Id:number) {
    this._router.navigate(['../editemployeebyidcomponent'], {})            
}
```

Comment: can you post your routing configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to provide router outlet in you parent component so allow angular to render child on it so in your example you have to declare a parent component lets say Employee.component.ts and it's equivalent template Employee.component.html and inside .html write that directive  don't forget to declare this parent inside your **EmployeeModule**

```
const  employeeRoutes: Routes = [
  {path : 'employee', component: EmployeeComponent,children: [
    {path : 'editemployeebyidcomponent', component: EditEmployeeByIdComponent},
    ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(employeeRoutes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    EmployeeComponent,EditEmployeeByIdComponent
  ],
  exports :[RouterModule]
})
export class EmployeeModule { }
```

**employee.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
const  appRouts: Routes = [
  {path: 'employee' , component: EmployeeComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRouts),
  ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

your navigation route inside parent component  should be like that

```
 GetById(Id:number) {
        this._router.navigate(['../editemployeebyidcomponent'],{relativeTo: this.currentActivatedRoute})
```

}

Either you make the route absolute

```
 GetById(Id:number) {
        this._router.navigate(['/editemployeebyidcomponent'])
```

}